# Вставить картинку в таблицу Google Docs

Tags: google-apps-script

Мне нужно с помощью Google App Script вставить в таблицу Google Docs (не Google Sheets) картинку. Таблица создана заранее и состоит из одной ячейки для картинки. Не знаю поможет ли это, но вот мой изначальный код. Он не вставляет именно в таблицу а просто в документ. Заранее спасибо!

```js
function onOpen() {
  var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
    .addItem('First item', 'menuItem1')
    .addToUi();
}

function menuItem1() {
  var fileId = '1YDA3MTuIvrZD4wOgOAJE1NiLY_q9oHKu';
  var ss = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var img = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getBlob();
  ss.getBody().insertImage(0, img);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы предпочел добавлять картинку в параграф, как бы странно это ни звучало.

```
function run() {
  const image = DriveApp.getFileById('1nVNdbt9SY42c-A30X5iSK4RaMcKCk2pt');
  const paragraph = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()
    .getBody()
    .getTables()[0] // в первую таблицу
    .getRow(0)      // в первую строку
    .getCell(1)     // во вторую ячейку
    .getChild(0)    // с нулевым индексом всегда будет `Paragraph`
    .asParagraph(); // The paragraph in a specific cell
  paragraph.insertInlineImage(0, image.getBlob());
}
```

`Paragraph` - единственный класс, кроме `Body`, который умеет почти все.

Обратите внимание, что этот метод не меняет размер картинки. Основная идея по изменению размера картинки [тут](https://github.com/contributorpw/google-apps-script-snippets/commit/6dde215e53324431f81ceeb1717170f8cfc16248#diff-025104f2a09d36eafb4d1177721708210f4d4a66530566b693a9d016c7197c07R2-R28).

Comment: Спасибо большое, всё работает!

Comment: @freereal-estate, отметьте ответ как решение.